# My append command won't work (Python)

Tags: python

I am a new programmer and I am teaching myself using Sams Teach Yourself Python in 24 Hours, and one of the excersises told me to rewrite a piece of code that allows the clerk to work out orders at a restraunt and it told me change it so to include the price, so I did, but I want to use the user's input of the price and to put it into a list to sum it up and print out the total. However, it doesn't work. What should I do?

Here is the code:

```
breakfast_special = "Texas Omelet"
breakfast_notes = "Contains brisket, horseradish cheddar"
lunch_special = "Greek patty melt"
lunch_notes = "Like the regular onem but with tzatziki sauce"
dinner_special = "Buffalo Steak"
dinner_notes = "Top loin with hot sauce and blue cheese, NOT BUFFALO MEAT"

while True:
    meal_time = raw_input("Which mealtime do you want? [breakfast, lunch, dinner, q to quit]")
if meal_time == "q":
    break
price = raw_input("Price: $")
price.append(price)
total_price = sum.price

if meal_time == "breakfast":
    print "Specials for {} :".format(meal_time)
    print breakfast_special
    print breakfast_notes
elif meal_time == "lunch":
    print "Specials for {} :".format(meal_time)
    print lunch_special
    print lunch_notes
elif meal_time == "dinner":
    print "Specials for {} :".format(meal_time)
    print dinner_special
    print dinner_notes
else:
    print "Sorry, but {} isn't a valid choice".format(meal_time)

print "Goodbye!"
print "Price: ${}".format(total_price)
```

Comment: Fix your indentation first.

Comment: your variable and list both got the same name `price`. Change the list name for example to `prices`. then call the `sum` function on it. like this: `sum(prices)`

Comment: "put it into a list" - What list? You never made one. You can't just append to a number and expect it to create a `list` for you.

Comment: On top of that, you're appending it to itself, and then you have the entirely wrong syntax for using the `sum` function. I recommend the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: What is this: `price.append(price)` line supposed to do?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid `price.append(price)` is meant to add a value into a list of its own, which I thought would do, but as @TigerhawkT3 pointed out, it doesn't automatically make me a new list.

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input()` takes a string input.

So when you try to do `price = raw_input()` , the user input is saved as string type to your variable 'price'. To convert that value to int/float, you can do `int(price)` or `float(price)`

Note: You have to make sure the user_input is actually a number. If the variable 'price' has characters, converting it to int/float will result in a `ValueError`

To achieve what you're trying to do, let's do the following.

first: allocate a new list to hold all the prices you are taking as input. lets call it price_list.

`price_list = []`

now let's take floating point input form the user for price and append it to the price_list

```
price = float(raw_input('Price for the item :'))
price_list.append(price)
```

now that we have a list of prices, lets get the sum of all the prices.

```
sum(price_list)
```

That should give you the total sum.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I wonder why this answer had a downvote... I see nothing wrong with it

Comment: As a matter of best practices, rather than suggesting that OP use `input()`, you should suggest that he use `raw_input()` and then convert the result to whatever type he needs. `input()` in Python 2 is dangerous.

Comment: @senshin Yes. I understand that. I suggested `input` because using `raw_input()` and then converting it to int/float type, requires him to have additional logic in place to make sure the user_input is valid and doesn't result in `ValueError`.

And since it is a beginner, I thought that'd complicate the response.

Comment: Do not suggest the use of `input()`, because [a] its not designed for what the OP is doing and [b] on Python3 it will have completely different results.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7. Which command would be ok to use? @senshin and Kiran?

Comment: @NewCoder use raw_input(). It works with both python 2.7 and 3.* . I also changed my answer to reflect raw_input()